# GWT: transmit an interface with an IsSerializable Object

Tags: gwt, interface, rpc

Good morning everybody,

I'm trying to transmit the following calls with an GWT RPC call:

```
public class MVCController extends Composite implements IsSerializable {
    //..        
    private MVCClass listeners;

    public void addListener(MVCClass _listener){
        listeners = _listener;
    }

    //....
}
```

The MVCClass is the following interface:

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

```
public interface MVCInterface extends IsSerializable{
    public abstract void labelTextChange(String _text);
}
```

Whenever I make the RPC call, the application crashes, saying something about

```
Failed to create an instance of ... via deferred binding
```

Can I send an Interface with an RFC call?

Regards Stefan

Comment: Can we see the code that makes the RPC call?  Also: sometimes compiling the app produces more detailed error messages than just running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not serialize a gwt widget that is why you get that exception. Your class `MVCController` extends from `Composite` whose base class is `Widget`..

Comment: yeah, but that was not my only mistake, also abstract classes and interface cant be serializised